# Booting Arch Linux using UEFI directly

Tags: linux, boot, installation, arch-linux, uefi

I tried to install Arch Linux on my HP laptop such that it would boot directly from UEFI. I did it before but I don't remember exact method I used. I follow standard instructions form wiki and have `/dev/sda1` mounted at `/mnt/boot` and `/dev/sda2` mounted at `/mnt`. After chrooting in `/mnt` I use pacman to download efibootmgr. Then I use the command:

`efibootmgr -d /dev/sda -p 1 -c -L "Arch Linux" -l /vmlinuz-linux -u "root=/dev/sda2 rw initrd=/initramfs-linux.img"`

following wiki again. I always make sure that boot order is proper but after reboot, computer doesn't see any bootable system.

Then using UEFI shell from USB I wanted to try

`Shell> bcfg boot add N fsV:\vmlinuz-linux "Arch Linux"`

but my shell only lists USB as fs0 and everything else is listed as blk0, blk1 and so on. They are not accesible directories so I can't use these in command above.

I don't know what else could I try. I burnt USB using rufus and I tried most of the options. Currently I used drive formatted GPT, FAT32 and I used DD mode with rufus. I have legacy and secure boot disabled in BIOS. Laptop's disk is formatted GPT and `/dev/sda1` is EFI partition. Both partitions are formatted as ext4 using `mkfs.ext4`. I tried multiple times reainstalling the system but I still can't figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: Sometimes EFIs get confused and can no longer accept new boot entries. Using the firmware setup utility to reset all firmware options to their defaults *may* fix this problem, but I can make no promises about that.

Answer (score 2):

I do not trust in efibootmgr so I like to do this manually, If I missing something please write a comment.

First you need to boot from the USB installation media in UEFI mode. I try to highlight the arch installation process UEFI part.

The UEFI boot required not just efi but a boot partition too.

First two partition should look like this:
boot 1M size and start at the first sector. then a 500M efi partition.

```
fdisk -l
Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048      4095      2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096   1028095   1024000  500M EFI System
```

I recommend gdisk to create them.

Both should be formated as FAT:

```
mkfs.vfat /dev/sda1
mkfs.vfat /dev/sda2
```

Mount root FS to /mnt as you would do then create a esp folder in the /mnt and mount efi partition as the following:

```
mkdir /mnt/esp
mount -o rw,relatime,fmask=0033,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro /dev/sda2 /mnt/esp
```

At this point the pacstrap and then genfstab could be done from the UEFI point of veiw.

add the following to the end of the /mnt/etc/fstab file.

```
/esp/EFI/arch   /boot   none    bind    0 0
```

This required because the pacman update the /boot while the boot loader will looking the files in /esp/EFI/arch so system become unbootable after an update.

now you have to edit /etc/mkinitcpio.conf HOOKS= section, should look like this:

```
HOOKS='base systemd autodetect modconf block sd-lvm2 filesystems keyboard fsck sd-shutdown'
```

sd-lvm2 only required if you using lvm partitions.

Now this point we have to chroot into /mnt

run this commands :

```
mkinitcpio -p linux
bootctl --path=/esp install # install boot loader
echo -e "# Load vfat at boot\nvfat\n" > /etc/modules-load.d/vfat.conf   # Load vfat module at boot
```

Create a file /esp/loader/entries/arch.conf contain the folowing:

```
title   Arch Linux
linux   /EFI/arch/vmlinuz-linux
#initrd  /EFI/arch/intel-ucode.img
initrd  /EFI/arch/initramfs-linux.img
options root=/dev/sda3 rw
```

`initrd  /EFI/arch/intel-ucode.img` line should be uncommented if you using intel cpu you also have to install `pacman -Sy intel-ucode` for intel cpu, root= should contain the system root partition.

the config file looking files under /EFI/arch/ so we create the directory and copy every file from /boot then delete /boot/* since we will bind mount /EFI/arch/ to /boot when the system will boot up.

```
mkdir -p /esp/EFI/arch
cp /boot/* /esp/EFI/arch/
rm /boot/*
```

If every else is done you like to config in chroot, you could try to boot up the new system.

Comment: Actually, the BIOS boot partition is irrelevant in this case and neither should it be formatted.

Answer (score 0):

If your EFI System Partition isn’t formatted as FAT32, then that’s the problem. While theoretically UEFI may support any file system, the only fs it *has* to support is FAT32. (Maybe some CD/DVD fs too.)

The ESP must be FAT32.